# How to properly terminate an openGL application?

Tags: opengl, c++, glfw

I use GLFW in C++.
I close my application the following way:

```
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
    glDeleteProgram(renderingProgram);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Is this the correct way of closing the application, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Apparently, the documentation says that you only need to call glfwTerminate. Did you encounter any issues with your implementation?

Comment: Yeah, the docs say to *typically* initialize with `glfwInit()` and close with `glfwTerminate()`. Are you doing something non-typical that warrants special behavior?

Comment: No, there was no issues, I was just not sure if some memory still stays allocated. Then I guess everything should be fine. Thanks for the answers!